# Is a toolbar icon supposed to show?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have the following code and I'm on OSX. However, I'm expecting to see a toolbar icon but I'm not seeing one. Am I doing something wrong or should it work on Windows? Here's the code

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title): 
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title,size=(400, 350))

        self.InitUI() 
        self.Centre() 
        self.Show()

    def InitUI(self):

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        toolbar = wx.ToolBar(self, size=(-1, 128))
        toolbar.SetToolBitmapSize((128,128))


        bmp2 = wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_ADD_BOOKMARK, wx.ART_OTHER, (128,128))

        toolbar.AddLabelTool(-1, label="Add", bitmap=bmp2, 
                                         shortHelp="Add", kind=wx.ITEM_NORMAL)

        toolbar.Realize()
        self.SetToolBar(toolbar)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App() 
    Example(None, title='') 
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks

Comment: Running your code on windows 7 i see a toolbar icon.

Comment: @Yoriz Thanks. I guess it acts up only on OSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `Realize` needs to happen after the `SetToolBar`.  This is because there are two different kinds of toolbars on OSX and which is chosen depends on if it is attached to a frame or not, and all that happens in the `Realize` call.  Also, OSX is picky about the size of the tools, and the 128 you use will likely be reduced to a supported size.